# PHP sessions in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, php

Having an issue with the intranet I'm developing for my company. It's hosted locally on our server and uses PHP. It has a login script which works fine with Firefox and Chrome, but when I try to login with Internet Explorer it just takes me back to the main login page and doesn't execute the script at all. I think it has something to do with the PHP session and generating a new session ID, any ideas? Here my code

```
    $//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: index.htm");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['ID'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_fname'] = $member['fname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_lname'] = $member['lname'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_username'] = $member['username'];               

        session_write_close();
        header("location: login_success.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        header("location: login-failed.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: PHP doesn't generate different sessions based on browser type. Check that the session cookie in IE is actually "sticking". If it's not, then PHP will create a new empty session for every hit from IE.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Make sure you have cookies enabled.

Comment: Does that IE you tested on accept cookies?

Comment: I'm using IE9, and yes it's accepting cookies. Marc, is there a method to check if they're actually sticking?

Comment: The redirect just takes me back to the main page, http://192.168.1.5/